# jQuery setIntervel until condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

After the page is loaded i like to check a condition after every 1 second until it becomes true, and then terminate that function. I tried the following script that simple putting heavy load on the page start.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; ) {
      if ($(".showPrice").length) {
        console.log("yes");
        i = 1;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be able to clear the [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) you need a reference to the interval and pass it to [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval), just assign it to a variable:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let interval = setInterval(function () {
    if ($(".showPrice").length) { 
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log('Cleared!');
    }
  }, 1000);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.placeholder').html('<div class="showPrice">11.00 $</div>');
  }, 3000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
</body>
```